# Is it possible to mock IHubcontext<T> using Moq Framework?

Tags: c#, signalr-hub, .net-5

I have a controller which has a `IHubContext<T>` object injected into the constructor. I would like to unit test adding and removing `connectionId`s to and from  groups. I am asking how I can do this?
I tried this:

```
public interface IMyHubContext :IHubContext<MyHub>
{
    Task AddToGroupAsync(string connectionId, string groupName, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);

    Task RemoveFromGroupAsync(string connectionId, string groupName, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}
```

```
var cs = new CancellationTokenSource();
var ct = cs.Token;


Mock<IMyHubContext> hubMoq = new Mock<IMyHubContext>();
hubMoq.Setup(a => a.RemoveFromGroupAsync("123", $"{groupName}", ct)).Returns(null);
```

But this generates a compile time error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compile time error is generated probably due to passing `null` to `Returns`. Since, `RemoveFromGroupAsync` return type is `Task`, I think you need to set up this call as below:

```
hubMoq.Setup(a => a.RemoveFromGroupAsync("123", $"{groupName}", ct))
      .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
```